# Chord diagram with only one path between any two events

Tags: r, chord-diagram, circlize, chord

I would like to have a chord diagram with only one path between any two events, this is my R code:

```r
library(stringr)
library(circlize)

Subject <- 1:137
set.seed(123)

# Create 'EventA' variable with binomial distribution
EventA <- rbinom(137, size = 1, prob = 0.68)
EventB <- rbinom(137, size = 1, prob = 0.62)
EventC <- rbinom(137, size = 1, prob = 0.81)
EventD <- rbinom(137, size = 1, prob = 0.55)
EventE <- rbinom(137, size = 1, prob = 0.71)
EventF <- rbinom(137, size = 1, prob = 0.77)
data <- data.frame(Subject, EventA, EventB, EventC, EventD, EventE, EventF)

data$Subject <- str_sub(data$Subject, -5, -1)
#############################################
events <- as.matrix(data[, -1])

num_sectors <- ncol(events)

co_occurrence <- t(events) %*% events

diag(co_occurrence) <- 0

event_names <- c("EventA", "EventB", "EventC", "EventD", "EventE", "EventF")

event_numerosity <- colSums(data[,c(-1,-8)])

event_labels <- paste(event_names, "N = ", event_numerosity)

colnames(co_occurrence) <- rownames(co_occurrence) <- event_labels

print(co_occurrence)

grid.col <- setNames(rainbow(length(unlist(dimnames(co_occurrence)))), union(rownames(co_occurrence), colnames(co_occurrence)))

chordDiagram(co_occurrence, grid.col = grid.col)
```

With this code I get this graph

[image]

If possible, could it be done with a single path between any two events?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your co-occurrence matrix is symmetrical, so it shows the same flow in both directions for each pair. Simply remove either the upper or lower triangle from the matrix to remove one set of flows:

```r
co_occurrence[upper.tri(co_occurrence)] <- 0
chordDiagram(co_occurrence, grid.col = grid.col, annotationTrack = c("name","grid"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Allan, this graph looks much better than mine.
I would ask you one more thing: 
- would it be possible to remove the small numbers written above each sector? Those ranging from 0 to 360 for eventF for example

Comment: Sure, see my update @Bibi

Comment: I don't know how to thank you! This is really perfect. Last thing really, this graphic shows me the detail of EventF and EventE well (the paths keep the colours of these two events, whereas for example for eventA, the paths all have different colours). If I were mainly interested in EventA, how can I do to keep the colours of EventA for the paths?

Comment: @Bibi just plot `t(co_occurrence)` instead of `co_occurrence`

Comment: Many thanks Allan, really helpful!

Comment: I am So sorry, but I am being asked how to do this in these two cases:
1) I would be interested in EventF and then EventA (instead of EventF and EventE as in the picture) then change the clockwise direction;
2) I would be interested in EventD and EventB (so not two neighbouring events)

Comment: @Bibi try using the `order` parameter inside `chordDiagram` - something like `order = event_labels[c(1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6)]`.